# Insert a black frame between each frame and double the output FPS

Tags: ffmpeg, frame

So I am looking for a way to add a black frame in between each frame of a current video.  What I am trying to do it add a blanking phase to a video to give it a film look.   So the pipeline is a 59.94 fps video and add a black frame in between each of the source video frames and create an output video that is 120fps with a real frame, black frame, real frame, black frame, etc.   Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If

1. your video is constant frame-rate, and
2. you know the framerate,

you can run

```
ffmpeg -i in -vf fps=120000/1001,drawbox=t=fill:c=black:enable='mod(n\,2)' -c:a copy out
```

where `120000/1001` is supposed to be double the input fps.

Comment: This gives an error:
[Parsed_drawbox_1 @ 0x7fffc3e49640] Cannot find color 'black=enable=mod(n,2)'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fffc3e59740] Error initializing filter 'drawbox' with args 't=max:c=black=enable=mod(n\,2)'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

Comment: @ToddBryant There was a typo. See updated answer.

Comment: Looks like it is working.  I will let you know.  Thanks

Comment: Is there anything one needs to add to ensure it's a remux and not a transcode? I'm getting a much smaller file on the output side than the input side.

Comment: If a stream has filters applied, then it has to be transcoded.